# How can I configure Ubuntu to require answers to random math problems in place of a password?

Tags: login, pam, education

For the home Linux laptop (running Ubuntu 18.04), for the kids, I would like to be able to configure the computer to require answer(s) to randomly selected math problems to log in, rather than requiring a password.  (For a specific user account only, for graphical login only.)

I've searched the internet but haven't found anything about this.  It doesn't seem likely that I'm the first one to think of this idea, but internet searches do suggest that.  :)

Security isn't an issue since the only people with physical access to the computer are all trusted.  (If there is anything I should configure to disallow SSH access or for other security concerns, you could mention it, but I doubt my ISP would let port 22 traffic through from the internet anyway.)

The benefits should be obvious, but to be explicit about them - the point is that there could be a mild barrier to "getting screen time" that would involve something a little bit educational.

I am currently using Gnome with sddm as the display manager, but I don't know if that really matters.

Comment: This is probably something that would need to be implemented via PAM: someone claims to have done it here [Linux Pam authentication by answering to a challenge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17896361/linux-pam-authentication-by-answering-to-a-challenge) but apparently didn't share their implementation

Comment: This may be easier to do with a custom screen lock -- you could *possibly* add xautolock to ~/.config/autostart with something like `xautolock -locknow -locker myQuizUtility`. It would lock the screen automatically on login till myQuizUtility released it and could also be set to lock again after a set amount of time. Could be a fun project.